# nx.dev creating first app failure with cannot find module

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, nx.dev

In trying out nx.dev, I ran this command

```
npx nx generate @nrwl/node:app ghApi
```

and received this error

```
Unable to resolve @nrwl/node:app.
Cannot find module '@nrwl/node/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev-workspace/node_modules/nx/src/utils/nx-plugin.js
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev- workspace/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev-workspace/node_modules/nx/src/command- line/generate.js
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev-workspace/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/nx-commands.js
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev-workspace/node_modules/nx/bin/init-local.js
- /Users/dean/workspace/gazehealth/nxdev-workspace/node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js
```

I simply followed instructions from https://nx.dev/getting-started/nx-and-typescript
any ideas?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9419?

Comment: odd, they close the issue without fixing the documentation.  ok, thanks!!!   I did not stumble on that one when I was googling around.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

Try: `nx report`

You will see something like this:

```
 >  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node : 16.15.0
   OS   : darwin x64
   npm  : 8.5.5
   
   nx : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/angular : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/cypress : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : Not Found
   @nrwl/express : Not Found
   @nrwl/jest : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/js : Not Found
   @nrwl/linter : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/nest : Not Found
   @nrwl/next : Not Found
   @nrwl/node : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : Not Found
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : 14.2.2
   @nrwl/web : Not Found
   @nrwl/workspace : 14.2.2
   typescript : 4.7.3
```

In my case `@nrwl/node` was "not found"

So I just Installed it with: `npm i @nrwl/node`

And after that, the `nx g @nrwl/node:app MyAppName` worked.

I hope this can help!

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well - in my case I was trying to create a react library with `npx nx generate @nx/react:library react-sdk`, but I had to install `@nx/react` as a devDep first.

Answer (score 1):

These issues are sometimes related to node versions.
Check which node version you used to install the dependencies.

In my case, I used node 14 instead of node 16

After the node upgrade and reinstalling of all the node packages, the application did work fine.